# C#: Respond to serial event in certain time

Tags: c#, serial-port, avr

In my project I want to communicate over the serial port to a device which is controlled by an AVR microcontroller. On the AVR runs a timer which executes a loop every 10ms. The loop has about 2ms to execute and at the end it sends a message to the serial port for requesting the next command. On my computer runs a C# windows forms application which should respond to this request in the remaining 8ms so that the AVR has the new command for the next loop. I have a first prototype running which can respond most of the time in about 2-3ms so it should be possible to achive the desired performance. The problem is that sometimes(~twice per seconds) it takes longer(up to 20ms) for a response which causes my device to malfunction.

Does somebody know a solution to this problem?

Baudrate is 115200kbps, request is 1 byte, respond command are 6 bytes. Computer is a Mobile Workstation with i7 processor (4cores/8threads) which is more or less idle.

Temporary solution: I changed the sampling time from 10ms to 50ms. I will have to run some tests to see if the performance is good enough.

Comment: This is possible only in real time OS. In Windows you can try many tricks with process priority etc., but it will never work for 100%. Is device is so unflexible? If there is no any workaround, this device can be controlled only by another hardware device, possibly embedded device working in real time.

Comment: Maybe you could get better results if you are in kernel mode. You could create an interface to the device in the form of a serial filter driver and expose your own interface in to that driver. Then you can do all your time critical work there and post results to your application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot make this work.  Windows isn't anything like an AVR microcontroller.  Your Winforms program isn't the only thing it runs, it has to service a bunch of other processes and drivers as well.  Which certainly means that your Winforms program is sometimes not going to run for a while, 45 msec is common on a loaded machine, hundreds of msec is not unheard of.  Or the program is just plain out in the woods, collecting garbage.  Gen #2 GC pauses cannot be ignored in a .NET program.

You'll need to rethink your approach.